# Create a trial account for new users to test a web app build with Firebase: How should I count a trial period?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

**Product: Web App.**
**Technologies: Firebase, JavaScript, Cloud Functions.**

Hello I am dealing with the task of creating a **trial account for new users** in order of testing an app to know if it fits theirs requirements.Then, within trial time, users can decide if they want to suscribe or not.

This is my initial idea:

1. A potential new user discovers the landing page of the app
2. The user is interested in the app and creates a new account
3. The new account has a trial period (15 days free)
4. Whithin this trial period the user has to subscribe (Stripe) or the account is disabled/removed

I know that Stripe can deal with trial periods, but you first have to fill the payment data (credit card, etc). I want to avoid this, so I want to control the trial time and let the user try the app without asking him for payment data.

**My cuestion is that after creating the user account, in which way could I count the trial period ?**

Do I have to use Cloud Functions to count the trial period? Any orientation about how to count the trial period with Cloud Functions? Do I have to check the new accounts every day or something like that or is there any other way to get a notice after the trial period is over?

Any other approches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My cuestion is that after creating the user account, in which way could I count the trial period ?

When the user creates an account, store a timestamp of creation date for your document. When the user logs in, check if this timeStamp has passed 15 days or not.
You can also capture the time of creating the account in your app, add to it 15 days in the future, and then save this new [expiry date] in your user account info document.

Whenever this user logs in, first check, if the expiry date is before\after the current date. If it's after the current date(time of login), do your logic and tell them that the trial period is over.

Comment: In your application, write one line of code, when the app starts to check if the current date has passed the expiry date, if true.. `firebaseauth.instance.currentuser.signout`,

Comment: I am not talking about that, just telling that a user can sign in and he does not have to sign out, and next time would already be logged. Then when the user logs in is not a frequent action and therefore is not a good approach use when the user logs in as a chance to check whether the trial period is over.

Comment: When your home screen loads, whatever page you don't want them to see, do your check there in initstate of this page. Not the login page

Comment: Ok, in the page user is send (if user is already logged or after he logs in), check there. The only problem is if there is no activity from the user and you want to remove the account after the trial period... If there is no activity , thee is no check... Finally cloud function for that case I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to run a cloud function everyday to check all your user documents, and if they are expired, you want to delete them? What if my account expired, and I have plans to buy a subscription in a few days when I have money, but when I come to buy, I found that you deleted my account. I will not pay for the app, and so will many other users also. This will also allow your users to register again, using the same email, and get another free trial period, because you had removed their old documents, which is even worse for business.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I agree with him if they are planning to pay in next few days or even month .. I recommend to use above idea and show user page or even a popup that says the Trial has been expired if you want to continue use the app buy a plan which can redirects to the page which the user will buy the plan.

Comment: How secure is this approach could a user change or by pass the comparison logic ??